# Shiny - adding/appending user-selected observations to a list of observations to analyze

Tags: r, shiny

The user interface of the Shiny app I'm working on is supposed to work in the following manner:

1. User finds the desired observation(s) after applying a set of filters.
2. User clicks "Add" action button, so selected observation(s) are added to a running list/vector/etc of observations to be analyzed.
3. User modifies filters to find other observations which are to be included as well.
4. Loop back to step 1 as many times as user desires.

I cannot seem to find a way to save this list of observations to be analyzed. In the example I attached, the "observation ID" is the name of the model of the car (mtcars is used). I also did not include any data analysis, since I do not think that's necessary. In essence, the entire dataset (mtcars) should be filtered using dplyr in a reactive environment to only include the running list of selected observations.

Here's the code:

```
data("mtcars")
mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    
    titlePanel("sample"),
    
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("disp"),
            uiOutput("qsec"),
            uiOutput("model"),
            actionButton("add", "Add"),
            uiOutput("selectedModel")
        ),
        
        
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("data_analysis")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$disp <- renderUI({
        selectInput(
            "disp_sel",
            "Select disp:",
            unique(mtcars$disp),
            selected = NULL,
            multiple = T,
            selectize = T
        )
    })
    
    output$qsec <- renderUI({
        
        temp = mtcars
        
        if (!is.null(input$disp_sel)){temp = temp %>% filter(disp %in% input$disp_sel)}
        
        selectInput(
            "qsec_sel",
            "Select qsec:",
            unique(temp$qsec),
            selected = NULL,
            multiple = T,
            selectize = T
        )
    })
    
    output$model <- renderUI({
        temp = mtcars
        if (!is.null(input$disp_sel)){temp = temp %>% filter(disp %in% input$disp_sel)}
        if (!is.null(input$qsec_sel)){temp = temp %>% filter(qsec %in% input$qsec_sel)}
        
        selectInput(
            "model_sel",
            "Select model:",
            unique(temp$model),
            selected = NULL,
            multiple = T,
            selectize = T
        )
        
    })
    
    output$selectedModel <- renderUI({
        req(input$add)
        
        selectInput(
            "list_of_selections",
            "Selected models:",
            unique(mtcars$model),
            selected = NULL, # this should change when "Add" is pressed
            multiple = T,
            selectize = T
        )
        
    })
    
    r_data = eventReactive(input$add,{
        mtcars %>% filter(model %in% input$list_of_selections)
    })
    
    output$data_analysis <- renderPlot({
        # do something with r_data (filtered data)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've looked into modular code, reactive lists, and other stuff I don't even remember... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data("mtcars")
mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)

df1 <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  titlePanel("sample"),
  
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("disp"),
      uiOutput("qsec"),
      uiOutput("model"),
      actionButton("add", "Add"),
      uiOutput("selectedModel")
    ),
    
    
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("selecteddata"),
      plotOutput("data_analysis")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$disp <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "disp_sel",
      "Select disp:",
      unique(mtcars$disp),
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = T,
      selectize = T
    )
  })
  
  output$qsec <- renderUI({
    
    temp = mtcars
    
    if (!is.null(input$disp_sel)){temp = temp %>% filter(disp %in% input$disp_sel)}
    
    selectInput(
      "qsec_sel",
      "Select qsec:",
      unique(temp$qsec),
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = T,
      selectize = T
    )
  })
  
  output$model <- renderUI({
    temp = mtcars
    if (!is.null(input$disp_sel)){temp = temp %>% filter(disp %in% input$disp_sel)}
    if (!is.null(input$qsec_sel)){temp = temp %>% filter(qsec %in% input$qsec_sel)}
    
    selectInput(
      "model_sel",
      "Select model:",
      unique(temp$model),
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = T,
      selectize = T
    )
    
  })
  
  selected_data <- eventReactive(input$add,{
    df1 %>% filter(model %in% input$model_sel)
  })
  
  output$selecteddata <- renderDT(
    selected_data(), # reactive data
    class = "display nowrap compact", # style
    filter = "top", # location of column filters
    options = list(  # options
      scrollX = TRUE # allow user to scroll wide tables horizontally
    )
  )
  
  output$selectedModel <- renderUI({
    req(input$add)
    
    selectInput(
      "list_of_selections",
      "Selected models:",
      choices = unique(selected_data()$model),
      selected = unique(selected_data()$model), # this should change when "Add" is pressed
      multiple = T,
      selectize = T
    )
    
  })
  
  r_data = eventReactive(input$add,{
    mtcars %>% filter(model %in% input$list_of_selections)
  })
  
  output$data_analysis <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=selected_data(), aes(x=disp, y=qsec)) + geom_point()
    # do something with r_data (filtered data)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the sidebar functionalities are unchanged... I need for the app to be able to choose for example "Mazda RX4", save this to "Selected models" when "add" is pressed, then user changes filters, comes to different model, for example "Hornet 4 drive" clicks "add" and then BOTH "Mazda RX4" and "Hornet 4 Drive" are shown in "Selected models"

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I included

```
selected <- reactiveValues(s = NULL)
observeEvent(input$add,{selected$s = c(selected$s, input$model})
```

into the server part. Then the selected models are stored in `selected$s`.